# Retain contenteditable in edit mode even when clicked on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I recently found a simple rich-text editor on `Mozilla developer network` it has a editable div with image toolbar(for options like **Bold** etc.,) here is the full implementation of [code](http://jsbin.com/oTImOXI/2/edit?html,css,js,output).

It has image toolbar to change text inside the editable div but when I replace image with `div` or `span` or `li` etc., the `onclick` function which is `formatDoc('bold')` do not work! ie., the 
It only works when I replace div or span with `img` or `button`.

Here is my code [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OgapAYAJ/1/edit?html,css,js,output) showing `div` and `img` tags, only onclick of img is working.

Is there any way to retain the contenteditable div in edit mode while I run `formatDoc('bold')` on the selected text and not loose focus to clicked div ?

Comment: The click event is taking the focus away from the editable div for some reason this is bizarre

Comment: yes, that's exactly the problem here.

Comment: @Deryck can you tell how to solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the `mousedown` event instead and prevent the event's default action.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/IZOzAKim/1/edit

Comment: Amazing !! thank you very much but can you make me understand why i should use onmousediwn event??

Comment: @Null: Once the `click` event has fired, the focus has already moved to the document body and the selection in the contenteditable element is lost. `mousedown` fires before the focus is lost and preventing the default action associated with the event (`return false` in the `onmousedown` attribute value in this case) prevents the focus change.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it does affect DIVs for some reason. While I didn't find a workaround for them - you can use a normal button for similar effect:

```
<button class="hi" onclick="formatDoc('bold');"> bold </button>
```

You can style the button as needed (e.g. to remove standard button appearance):

```
.hi{
  cursor:pointer;
  border: none;
  background: inherit
}

.hi:focus {
  outline:none
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/IDIJoCU/1/edit